# I am getting the exception while running below code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.chrome(executable_path="C:\Driver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("www.youtube.com")

print (driver.title)

driver.close()
```

for the above code I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: It should be `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Driver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")`, `Chrome` with capital `C` and Python style path.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend modular programming.

Set a function that returns the chrome driver like such:

```
# Opens chrome driver
def openChrome():

    # directory to chromedrive
    chromeDriver = "C:\Driver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
    return webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver)
```

Call this function like this:

```
url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
driver = openChrome()
driver.get(url)
```

So in the future if your driver isn't working, you don't have to change it on every script you will change it in one place (function)